# Is the HDD SMART failing?

Tags: hard-drive, logging, smart

My server has started to reboot on random times for no reason.

I have been trying to locate the issue for a long time, at first I thought it was the virtualization / proxmox that or some reason caused the reboots.

But now I am starting to suspect my HDD storage is failing. What do you all think, is the 2 months old drive already dead?

```
root@proxmox ~ # smartctl -a /dev/sda 
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-5.0.21-1-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Enterprise Capacity 3.5 HDD
Device Model:     ST4000NM0024-1HT178
Serial Number:    Z4F0S45P
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 091cb67e9
Firmware Version: SN06
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Feb  7 18:16:25 2020 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 414) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x50bd) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       159956709
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   095   094   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       38
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   096   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       3800350406
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   068   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       28583
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       37
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   048   040    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 29/30)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1155
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3594
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 23 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   030   003   000    Old_age   Always       -       159956709
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23992         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23991         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     23986         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     23975         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     23968         -
# 6  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     23950         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

What got me worried was this:

`1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   082   064   044    Pre-fail  Always       -       159956709`

Is that really right? did I read it correctly that there is 159956709 errors?

Comment: https://wiki.unraid.net/Understanding_SMART_Reports  "PLEASE completely ignore the RAW_VALUE number! " If the WORST falls below its THRESH, then the drive isn't right. But that isn't your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those entries ARE hard to understand even in the GUI smartmontools (which uses smartctl I think). Your power-on hours are 28,583 & your last extended test was 23,986hr so you could run that again if you're worried. If those test pass & your SMART error log is empty then I say your drive is fine & the issue is elsewhere. If you're truly paranoid you could boot to the manufacturer/OEM drive test tool ([link to SeaTools](https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)) to use their test; however I'd trust smartctl since OEM has an incentive (call me paranoid) to tell you the drive is OK when its not (since they may have to warrant it)