# Proxmox Reboots by itself

Tags: reboot, proxmox

I'm running Proxmox Virtual Environment 6.0-7

All machines are LXC Containers (14 atm)

Load is usually never over 2, and I got 16 cores.
Disks are two 1TB SSD disks and one extra HDD disk for backup with 4TB storage.

The machine is running fine until it all of the sudden reboots. I have no idea why. I have tried to turn off all updates, I have for sure missed something but I cant understand what.

The disks are in good conditions according to another question/thread/idea I had: [Is the HDD SMART failing?](https://superuser.com/questions/1523631/is-the-hdd-smart-failing)

I don't want the server to reboot, if it needs an update then I want to do it myself when there is low load and need for the machines.

This is from the log: /var/log/syslog the roobot is at 5:30 and I have no clue what happend. let me know which logs I might need to include.

```
Mar  7 05:28:02 proxmox postfix/qmgr[1158]: 18AF496A0D: removed
Mar  7 05:29:00 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Mar  7 05:29:00 proxmox systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Mar  7 05:29:00 proxmox systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Mar  7 05:30:00 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Proxmox VE replication runner...
Mar  7 05:30:00 proxmox systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Succeeded.
Mar  7 05:30:00 proxmox systemd[1]: Started Proxmox VE replication runner.
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox CRON[11782]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/pct start 113)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox CRON[11783]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/pct start 107)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/pickup[26241]: 6BDFC96A0D: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/cleanup[11805]: 6BDFC96A0D: message-id=<20200307043001.6BDFC96A0D@proxmox.domain.com>
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/qmgr[1158]: 6BDFC96A0D: from=<root@proxmox.domain.com>, size=614, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/pickup[26241]: 6F13E969C1: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/cleanup[11805]: 6F13E969C1: message-id=<20200307043001.6F13E969C1@proxmox.domain.com>
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/qmgr[1158]: 6F13E969C1: from=<root@domain.com>, size=614, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox pvemailforward[11810]: mail forward failed: user 'root@pam' does not have a email address
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/local[11809]: 6BDFC96A0D: to=<root@domain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.17, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/pvemailforward)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/qmgr[1158]: 6BDFC96A0D: removed
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox pvemailforward[11812]: mail forward failed: user 'root@pam' does not have a email address
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/local[11811]: 6F13E969C1: to=<root@domain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.16, delays=0.01/0/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/pvemailforward)
Mar  7 05:30:01 proxmox postfix/qmgr[1158]: 6F13E969C1: removed
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd-modules-load[457]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd-modules-load[457]: Inserted module 'ib_iser'
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd-modules-load[457]: Inserted module 'vhost_net'
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox lvm[448]:   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg0" monitored
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting Helper to synchronize boot up for ifupdown...
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Starting udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization...
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd-udevd[484]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd-udevd[484]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar  7 05:31:41 proxmox systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
```